# MySQL optimize a union-query by using a join-query instead

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have 3 tables - one for users, one for their incoming payments, and one for their outgoing payments. I want to display all incoming and outgoing payments in a single result set. I can do this with multiple `select`s and a `union` but it seems cumbersome, and I suspect its slow due to the subqueries - and the tables are extremely large (though I am using indexes). Is there a faster way to achieve this? Maybe using a `full outer join`?

Here is a simplified version of the schema with some example data:

```
create table users (
  id int auto_increment,
  name varchar(20),
  primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB;
insert into users (name) values ('bob'),('fred');

create table user_incoming_payments (
  user_id int,
  funds_in int
) engine=InnoDB;
insert into user_incoming_payments
values (1,100),(1,101),(1,102),(1,103),
(2,200),(2,201),(2,202),(2,203);

create table user_outgoing_payments (
  user_id int,
  funds_out int
) engine=InnoDB;
insert into user_outgoing_payments
values (1,100),(1,101),(2,200),(2,201);
```

And here is the ugly looking query which generates the result I want for user bob:

```
select * from (
 (select u.name, i.funds_in, 0 as 'funds_out' from users u
 inner join user_incoming_payments i on u.id = i.user_id)
 union
 (select u.name, 0 as 'funds_in', o.funds_out from users u
 inner join user_outgoing_payments o on u.id = o.user_id)
) a where a.name = 'bob'
order by a.funds_in asc, a.funds_out asc;
```

And here is as close as I can get to doing the same thing with `join`s - its not correct though because I want this result set to look the same as the previous and I wasn't sure how to use `full outer join`:

```
select *
from users u
right join user_incoming_payments i on u.id = i.user_id
right join user_outgoing_payments o on u.id = o.user_id
where u.name = 'bob';
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a332b9/8)

Comment: There's no such thing as a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL - although obviously you can simulate one in various ways. But, if that query generates the desired result, then a FULL OUTER JOIN is not what's wanted. Your query is fine (although I'm not certain that the super query is necessary)

Comment: Do you have sample data and results?

Comment: @Ivan: You can't see the sample data and results already in the question? If not, you're not reading very thoroughly.

Comment: It would be better to put the filter `where u.name = 'bob'` in the subqueries. Otherwise it will produce a intermediate table with all users joined with their payments, then it will have to find all the bobs in that.

Comment: But other than that, your union approach is the right way to do it.

Comment: I concur with Barmar. MySQL doesn't "push" the predicate `name = 'bob'` on the outer query into the inline view. MySQL is going to materialize a derived table that contains rows for both `bob` and `fred`. And until the most recent versions of MySQL, there were no indexes on derived tables. And there's no need for the derived table. Strawberry has it right (except that the query should be using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`) unless there's part of the specification we're missing that says "remove duplicate rows".

Answer (score 3):

With this model, I'd probably write that query as follows, but I doubt it makes much difference...

```
select u.name
     , i.funds_in
     , 0 funds_out 
  from users u
  join user_incoming_payments i 
    on u.id = i.user_id
 where u.name = 'bob'
 union all
select u.name
     , 0 funds_in
     , o.funds_out 
  from users u
  join user_outgoing_payments o 
    on u.id = o.user_id
 where u.name = 'bob'
 order 
    by funds_in asc
     , funds_out asc;
```

However, note that there's no PK here, which may prove problematic.

If it was me, I'd have one table for transactions, which would include a transaction_id PK, a timestamp for each each transaction, and a column to record whether a value was a credit or a debit.

Comment: Note that `UNION` will remove duplicates, which is probably not desirable in this scenario. We don't see any guarantee that there won't be two (or more) rows in `user_incoming_payments` with the same value of `funds_in`. We probably want to use a `UNION ALL` set operator to avoid removing duplicates. (Wherever removal of duplicates is not required, we prefer to use a `UNION ALL` for performance, to avoid the overhead of the check for duplicates.

Comment: Also, with this type of query, I typically include a discriminator column, that is, an extra column in each query, with each query returning a different, short literal value (maybe `'i'` and `'o'` in this scenario, which lets me know which query returned a row.

Comment: @spencer7593 Fixed (with caveats)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Even if it did support it, I don't think you would want that, as it would introduce a semi-cartesian product... with each row from `incoming_` matching every row in `outgoing_`, creating extra rows.

If there were four rows from `incoming_` and six rows from `outgoing_`, the set produced by a join operation would contain 24 rows.

This really looks more like you want a set concatenation operation. That is, you have two separate sets that you want to concatenate together. That's not a `JOIN` operation. That's a **`UNION ALL`** set operation.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
 UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ...
```

If you don't need to remove duplicates (and it looks like you wouldn't want to in this scenario, if there are multiple rows in `incoming_` with the same value of `funds_in`, I don't think you want to remove any of the rows.)...

Then use the `UNION ALL` set operator which does *not* perform the check for  and removal of duplicate rows.

The `UNION` operator removes duplicate rows. Which (again) I don't think you want.

---

The derived table isn't necessary.

And MySQL doesn't "push" the predicate from the outer table into the inline view.  Which means that MySQL is going to materialized a derived table with all incoming and outgoing for *all* users. And the the outer query is going to look through that to find the rows. And until the most recent versions of MySQL, there were no indexes created on derived tables.

See the answer from Strawberry for an example of a more efficient query.

With the small example set, indexes aren't going to make any difference. With a large set, however, you are going to want to add appropriate covering indexes.

Also, with queries like this, I tend to include a discriminator column that tells me which query returned a row.

```
 (
   SELECT 'i' AS src
        , ...
     FROM ...
 )
   UNION ALL
 (
   SELECT 'o' AS src
        , ...
     FROM ...
 )
   ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: he won't get duplicate rows because he's putting `funds_in` and `funds_out` in different columns of the subqueries.

Comment: @Barmar: But if there two rows from `incoming_` that have the same values for `user_id` and `funds_in`. The example data doesn't show any duplicates... But what if we inserted more rows into the `incoming_` table `(1,100),(1,100),(1,100)`.  We don't see any constraint that prevents that. Note that the `UNION` operation removes *all* duplicates from the combined set. It doesn't matter which set the rows come from... the entire combined set is scanned for duplicates.

Comment: Good point. I suspect that in the real application there's also a transaction time that distinguishes them, but with the schema we've been given you're correct.

Comment: @Barmar:  Yes. If this was a bank/credit union, likely there would be a unique transaction id on each `ingoing_` and `outgoing_` row. I know I don't want my credit union "collapsing" my deposits because they are duplicate amounts. And even if we were guaranteed there wouldn't be duplicates, I'd still use the `UNION ALL` just to avoid the overhead of the  sort needed to check for duplicates.

Comment: Indeed, I think I've done that myself for exactly that reason.

Comment: that's a good point about `union all` not collapsing results - i'll definitely want that. i still get the feeling that some kind of join would be more efficient but i just can't get one that gives the right result set in order to look at the execution operations and compare them to the `select union all select` type query.

Comment: Feelings can be notoriously unreliable. Unless there's some condition by which you are "matching" rows between incoming_ and outgoing_, then you don't want a join operation.  If what you have is a single set "transactions", separated into two subsets "incoming" and "outgoing", and you want to combine the two subsets back into a single set, then `UNION ALL` is the ticket. (And that makes us wonder why this wasn't created as a single table in the first place, with a discriminator column to indicate which subset a row belongs too. A simple predicate would allow us to separate the subsets.)